# Jupyter Notebook can't run cells -- TypeError: should_run_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transformed_cell'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Running `ipykernel@6.6.1` in an ubuntu 20.04 docker container. I get the following error when trying to run a cell in a jupyter notebook:

```
getting_started | Traceback (most recent call last):
getting_started |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 353, in dispatch_shell
getting_started |     await result
getting_started |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 648, in execute_request
getting_started |     reply_content = await reply_content
getting_started |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 326, in do_execute
getting_started |     and should_run_async(
getting_started | TypeError: should_run_async() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transformed_cell'
```

Someone has recently posted https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/842 issue on github, but no solution yet.